# .htaccess and rewriting rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htaccess and rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315314/htaccess-and-rewriting)

how can i rewrite something like this

```
http://website.com/sub.php?cat_id=3&photo_id=324
```

into something like this

```
http://sub.website.com/3/324/
```

with the htaccess file in the root folder

Best of regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(d+)/?$ sub.php=?cat_id=$1&photo_id=$2
```